# Webpack dev server and WebSockets

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Three quick questions:

1) Knowing full well the benefits of Socket.io, I still wanna know if it is possible to run a single webpack-dev-server that can server both http and ws. Everything online is oriented to using Socket.io and running dual servers for http / ws.

2) If indeed I must use Socket.io, how does local development (http server and ws server being separate) compare to production environments? Do production environments typically have two servers running for http and ws, or is it usually all one server?

3) If I can use a single webpack-dev-server instance and native WebSockets, how the heck does one configure devServer to serve ws? All online examples are around Socket.io dual server setup so I've gotten no where fast.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) `webpack-dev-server` can only **proxy** websocket connections, nothing more.

```
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/websocket': {
       target: 'ws://[address]:[port]',
       ws: true // important
    },
  }
}
```

2) There is no requirement that you should split your server into a HTTP and WS parts. To use both in javascript you can use [express-ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws). This is also available in other languages (Spring supports it, Django also).

Snippet below serves static files (like `webpack-dev-server`) along with giving you an websocket interface.

```
const express = require('express');
const expressWs = require('express-ws');

const app = express();
expressWs(app);

//serve static files, 'public/index.html' will be served as '/'
app.use(express.static('public'));

// normal express.js handler for HTTP GET
app.get('/hello', function(req, res, next){
  res.send('hello');
});

// websocket handler
app.ws('/websocket', function(ws, req) {
  ws.on('message', function(msg) {
    ws.send(msg);
  });
});

app.listen(3000);
```

3) Again, `webpack-dev-server` only serves your static files and there is no WS equivalent. You know what to expect when requesting `GET /file.txt HTTP 1.1`. WS is only a transport protocol.

Bonus: `socket.io` has generally fallen out of favour since all major browsers now support websockets and there is no need for fallback behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much Greg! This is perfect!

Answer (score -3):

For anyone else that arrives here at a complete loss for why their WDS proxy configuration does not seem to be proxying websockets, be careful you have not made the following configuration mistake.

### Bad

```js
proxy: {
  '/api': process.env.PROXY_URI,
  ws: true,
},
```

### Good!

```js
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: process.env.PROXY_URI,
    ws: true,
  },
},
```